# Proving $D := \{ \ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ \mid \ 1+x^2+y > 0 \ \}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $D := \{ \ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \  \mid \ 1+x^2+y > 0 \  \}$ Determine whether $D$ is an open set or closed set in $\mathbb{R^2}$

So far I have that $D$ is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Let $p = (p_0, p_1) \in D$ , it follows $1 + p_{0}^{2} + p_{1} > 0$

Let $u = (u_0, u_1) \in B_{\epsilon}(p)$, it follows
$$d(p, u) = \|p - u\| = \sqrt{(p_0-u_0)^2 + (p_1-u_1)^2} < \epsilon$$

My problem is coming up with a definition of $\epsilon$ so that I could prove: $1 + u_{0}^{2} + u_{1} > 0$ and therefore $B_{\epsilon}(p) \subseteq D$

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Concerning the equality $d(p, u) = \|p - u\| = \sqrt{(p_0-u_0)^2 + (p_1-u_1)^2} < \varepsilon$, I have two questions. What is $\varepsilon$? And how do you deduce from the inequality that $D$ is open?

Comment: No. I am guessing that $D$ is an open set and trying to prove it. The inequality follows from letting $u$ be an element in $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $p$. I am thinking that the solution would follow from coming up with a formula for $\epsilon$ and perhaps using triangle inequality?

Comment: The boundary of your set is $1+x^2+y=0$, i.e. a parabola. Find the distance from $p$ to parabola and set $\epsilon$ to half of that distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $D$ is open because, if you define $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ by $f(x,y)=1+x^2+y$, then $f$ is continuous and $D=f^{-1}\bigl((0,+\infty)\bigr)$. Besides, $(0,+\infty)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$.

And it is not closed because $\left(\left(0,-1-\frac1n\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of elements of $D$ which converges to $(0,-1)$, which is not an element of $D$.

Comment: Jose Carlos. Please elaborate: f is continuous , (0,\infty) is open, f^{-1}(0,\infty) =D open as the pre-image of an open set of a cont.  function.Why any more? And is not closed...Thanks, Peter

Comment: @PeterSzilas I am sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking me.

Comment: Carlos . If a set is open which you showed why do you need to show that it is not closed, second paragraph.Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Because it could be open **and** closed.